# Fail to write parquet file in S3

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3, parquet

I am writing spark's dataframe to aws storage using the following command:

```
df.write.mode(Overwrite).parquet(filepath)
```

for some reason I see that it fails (it keeps trying) and I am not sure why.
Looking into the print output I see the following suspicious line:

> InternalParquetRecordWriter - Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 0

I am using hadoop version 2.9.1 with spark version 2.1.1.

Schema:

```
root
 |-- userID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- x1c9da6bb3d7d71: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you add the schema of the dataframe to the question?

Comment: root
 |-- userID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- x1c9da6bb3d7d71: string (nullable = true)